# Why does Promise inside .then() in javascript gets executed at the same time?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

```
        const promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('promise1');
          }, 3000);
        });

        const promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('promise2');
          }, 3000);
        });

        promise2.then(function(value) {
          console.log(value);
          promise1.then(function(value) {
              console.log(value);
            });
        });
```

output: *after 3 seconds, both displays at the same time

promise2
promise1

What i'm expecting is, after 3 seconds, promise2 will be displayed first then after another 3 seconds, promise1 will be displayed because promise1 should only execute after the console log in promise2 .then().

Comment: Because the timers start when you *create* the promises. After (slightly over) three seconds *both* promises are resolved with values. If you want more control, defer creation (e.g. `const promise1 = () => new Promise((resolve) => { ... });`, then you can *call* `promise1().then(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

Promises are eager in evaluation, you can make them lazy by wrapping them in a Function.

```js
const promise1 = () => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('promise1');
          }, 3000);
        });
        
const promise2 = () => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve('promise2');
          }, 3000);
        });

promise2()
    .then(console.log)
    .then(() => promise1())
    .then(console.log)
```